# Singularities of complex numbers.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$f(z) =\frac{(e^{z−1}−1)(\cos(z)−1)}{z^3(z−1)^2}$$

I am looking for the singularities of this function. Is it true that it only has a simple pole at 1 and then another simple pole at 0?

Is there more to it?

Comment: I think that is correct.

Comment: In order to find the order of the pole, you need to find the Laurant expansion of $f$ around both $0$ and  $1$. It should be clear that the order of the pole is the order of the zero in the denominator, minus the order of the zero of the function in the numerator since both the numerator and the denominator are entire.

Answer (score 1):

You can just Taylor expand the numerator:

$$cos(z) - 1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$e^{z-1}-1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^k}{k!}$$

Then $f(z) = (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k-3}}{(2k)!})(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^{k-2}}{k!})$ which clearly has two simple poles at 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that the order of the pole is the order of the zero in the denominator, minus the order of the zero of the function in the numerator, since both the numerator and the denominator are entire. So since $e^{z-1}-1$ has a simple zero at $z=1$, and is not zero at $z=0$ and since $\cos(z) -1$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z = 0$ and is not zero at $z=1$, we conclude that there are simple poles at both $z = 1$, and $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: There isn't much more to it.

A direct way of "seeing" the poles is using the standard limits

- $\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{e^w-1}{w} = 1$
- $\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\cos w-1}{w^2} = -\frac{1}{2}$

Hence, you can write
$$f(z) =\frac{(e^{z−1}−1)(\cos(z)−1)}{z^3(z−1)^2} = \underbrace{\frac{e^{z−1}−1}{z-1}}_{\stackrel{z\to 1}{\longrightarrow}1}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\cos(z)−1}{z^2}}_{\stackrel{z\to 0}{\longrightarrow}-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$$

So, what is left are a two poles of order $1$ at $z= 0$ and $z=1$.